# Moving forward / backward using a hexadecimal offset

Tags: hexl-mode

There is `hexl-forward-char` which lets me move forward/backward specifying a decimal offset.

And there is also `hexl-goto-hex-address` to specify an *absolute* location using a hexadecimal number.

Is there perhaps also something builtin that lets me move by an hexadecimal offset, or do I need to roll my own here?

Comment: I'm not seeing any other movement commands calling `hexl-hex-string-to-integer`, so I think you'll have to roll your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upcoming nhexl-mode-1.0 (in GNU ELPA) changes `C-u` so it takes hexadecimal input.  IOW `C-u 10 C-f` will advance by 16 chars instead of 10.

Comment: It works! Where can I report nhexl-mode bugs?

Comment: You can send them directly to me or `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my own function. It seems to do the trick.

```
(defun hexl-hex-forward-char (hex-offset)
  "Move to right HEX-OFFSET bytes (left if negative) in Hexl mode."
  (interactive "sHex Offset: ")
  (hexl-goto-address
    (+ (hexl-current-address)
    (hexl-hex-string-to-integer hex-offset))))
```

And the following overwrites the key binding for `hexl-forward-word` which I don't use:

```
(add-hook 'hexl-mode-hook
          (lambda () (local-set-key (kbd "M-f") #'hexl-hex-forward-char)))
```